# Symfony3 - Add logger that log Doctrine queries

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

What is best practices to log the doctrine queries with monolog? I started with symfony a week ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your configuration, set the `doctrine.dbal.logging` to `true`.

```
# app/config/config.yml

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:  pdo_mysql
        # ...
        logging: true
```

In fact, queries are logged by default in dev environment by setting the value  through the `kernel.debug` parameter, e.g. `logging: %kernel.debug%`.

See [DoctrineBundle configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html).